# How do I programmatically modify Firefox preferences without restarting?

Tags: command-line, firefox

With [GCLI](https://github.com/joewalker/gcli/), this was as simple as

```
pref set <setting> <value>
```

Loading a `user.js` file requires restarting Firefox.  I want to toggle settings back and forth within a single session.

Comment: ["Programmatic changes to preferences can be made using the Preferences.jsm module from JS code"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Preferences/A_brief_guide_to_Mozilla_preferences#Modifying_preferences) but no example.  How do I import Preferences.jsm in "webconsole"?

Answer (score 5):

### Programmatically manage preferences

I wanted to programatically modify the browser preference for managing the proxy configuration. Trial and error showed that [`network.proxy.type`](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Network.proxy.type)) was the preference which controlled the proxy configuration and Internet research (how I found this question) showed that the way to dynamically modify browser preferences is to run JavaScript statements in Firefox’s *Browser Console command line*.

#### Using the Browser Console command line

Note that the [Browser Console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Browser_Console) is not the same as the *Web Console*:

> The Browser Console is like the [Web
> Console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console), but
> applied to the whole browser rather than a single content tab.

Also, note that the command line UI has to be enabled before use:

> The Browser Console command line is disabled by default. To enable it set
> the `devtools.chrome.enabled` preference to `true` in `about:config`, or set
> the "Enable chrome debugging" option in the developer tool settings.

The Browser Console can be opened with the following keyboard shortcuts:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>J</kbd> (PC keyboard)
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>J</kbd> (Mac keyboard)

#### Working with the Preferences API

My research showed that Firefox provides a [`Services.prefs`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/JavaScript_code_modules/Services.jsm) object which has a number of methods for getting and setting preferences –
depending on the type of the preference, e.g., Boolean, Integer, String.

I suspected that the `network.proxy.type` preference was most likely an Integer type as it can have useful values ranging from 0 to 5 (see [Network.proxy.type - MozillaZine Knowledge Base](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Network.proxy.type)). I verified this by using the [`getPrefType()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsIPrefBranch#getPrefType()) method and comparing its return value with that of `PREF_INT`:

```
>> Services.prefs.getPrefType("network.proxy.type") === Services.prefs.PREF_INT
True
```

I then used the [`getIntPref()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsIPrefBranch#getIntPref()) method to see what the preference was set to:

```
>> Services.prefs.getIntPref("network.proxy.type")
5
```

The MozillaZine Knowledge Base for [Network.proxy.type](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Network.proxy.type) describes `5` as corresponding to

> Use system proxy settings. (Default in Linux; default for all platforms,
> starting in 1.9.2.4 /Firefox 3.6.4).

I was able to use the [`setIntPref()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsIPrefBranch#setIntPref()) to change this value to `1` (use the *Manual proxy configuration*) by running:)

```
>> Services.prefs.setIntPref("network.proxy.type", 1)
```

Comment: For my own interst, I've started learning how to make Firefox extensions and I plan to eventually use this information to create a simple toggle button that also shows whether or not the manual proxy is enabled.